# How to show a row total amount by group CG Group in Report

Tags: report, axapta, x++

I am using Axapta 3.0 with language X++.

I am making a report based on available report. The new report only shows a total row by group CG Group instead of showing all detail row as old report.

Exam: Available report

```
CG Code Amount  Current     1-30days    31-60days   61-180days  >180days
1.1 50  10  100 30  10             5
----------
1.1 30  20  60  35  20             20
----------
1.1 20  30  80  7   80             60
----------
1.2 30  50  50  1   100            80
----------
1.2 40  70  90  5   75             15
----------
2.3 100 20  20  150 20             30
----------
3.1 60  10  10  80  10             4
----------
3.1 30  60  5   100 5              60
```

New report as sample:

```
CG Code    Amount   Current  1-30days  31-60days  61-180days >180days
1.1Total     100      60        240       92         110         85
----------
1.2Total      70     120        140        6          175         95
----------
2.3Total     100     20          20        150         0          30
----------
3.1Total      90     70           15      180          15         64
```

I see the code of available report has SQL sentence as

```
select AmountMST from CustTransOpen where
custTransOpen.AccountNum == CustTable.AccountNum
&& custTransOpen.TransDate <= balanceAs
&& CustTransOpen.TransDate >= compareDate1
&& CustTransOpen.TransDate <= compareDate2
```

I have created view to get data from 2table (Custtransopen, Custtable) with name SKV_CustAgỉng3, then I also write SQL to group CG Group as:

```
select sum(AmountMST),StatisticsGroup from SKV_CustAging3
group by StatisticsGroup
where SKV_CustAging3.TransDate <= balanceAs
&& SKV_CustAging3.TransDate < compareDate1;
```

I aslo try to use "Section Group" to total amount every CG Group but the report still shows detail record and  The end of section group shows total amount.

In my opinion, I want to show a row total amount by group CG Group the same example new report above.

**Are there any way to show only one record sum total for every CG?**

Please help me. I am new officers to make this report, so I don't many experience about Axapta.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override send() and fetch() methods of your report. Axapta call fetch() to fetch records which will be printed and Axapta calls send() method for each row, printed in the report.  Axapta developers guide contains a detailed information for this methods.

1. Override fetch() method and select all necessary data on it
2. Use instance of Map class to group the data
3. Call send() method to print data.

Find AOT by words "send" and "fetch" to get more examples.